# Should I use different jwt secret key on different role

Tags: jwt

I got 3 types of roles should I use 1 secret key for all roles or use a different key for each role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would just use 1 secret key for all roles, and recognizing the role with it's value in my database like role: "teacher", "student", "admin", etc ..